# How to work with meteor and laravel in an appl?

Tags: laravel-4, meteor

I tried to build a real-time web app.

The major app functionality is based on meteor.js.(Node.js MongoDb)

But I  want to let the User management, billing system(stripe), static pages based on laravel(PHP + Mysql).

They share the same user system, authentication. Exactly they are all part of the whole app.

But I have no idea how to combine both, especially the database schema.

Comment: You can make a pie with apples, and you can make a pie with pepperoni. But you wouldn't want to make a pepperoni apple pie. Your best bet would probably be to add OAuth to your existing Laravel app, and then create a separate Meteor application which connects its Accounts system to the Laravel app's OAuth flow.

Answer (score 0):

There does seem to be little written about architectures like this. Both meteor and Laravel are still relatively new. However I'm thinking of exactly the same combination with the following architecture. I am aware of the fact that I'm trying to combine a pizza with a steak (which might prove to be really tasty).

**What kind of app would be having this architecture?**

First the strengths and weaknesses (real short). Meteor is fast and provides an excellent communication layer between client and server. However it lacks a matured data layer. NoSQL db's (like: mongo) lack for example proper support for migrations and its just not as good documented as MySQL. Although I do think there might be a bright future for NoSQL, it's just not my choice for reliable applications 'yet'. Though I did see MySQL layers for Meteor, they are not closely as good as the Laravel MySQL layers.

Both applications have a really good interface layer and they are both nicely documented. They both run on Unix systems and scale pretty well in terms of code. Both Laravel and Meteor are event based.

With this knowledge it should be clear that apps like chats, auctions and other live stuff should be handled by Meteor. On the other hand, Structurizing complex / relational data should be done by Laravel. So if the app is small and has one goal. Stick with either Laravel or Meteor depending on the demands and don't try to combine them. However if you work on a bigger project having a static API with a MySQL database but also a chat functionality (for example facebook) go for a more distributed approach.

**Distributed cloud architecture**
Here's some reading material about distributed architectures.

[Distributed clouds](http://www.cloudcomputingpatterns.org/Distributed_Application)

In our use case Meteor will act as (what I call) a secretary reading from a NoSQL storage and instructing other applications/workers what to do with it's efficient asynchronous way of working. Laravel will more be in the processing layer allowing consistent processing. Laravel reads from and to a MySQL database and 'caches' what is normally the API output into the NoSQL storage that Meteor uses. The Laravel app can accept queue messages and will respond to http calls send from the meteor application

Soo: Clients <-> Meteor <-> MongoDB <-> Laravel <-> MySQL

Many projects start with a PHP laravel application, but suddenly demand a realtime functionality. For example a native IOS/Android app that displays static content and suddenly should be able to have a real time chat. That's where this architecture is actually pretty nice. The 2 applications are completely different but work together closely using a NoSQL storage or direct API calls.

Although they can both be on the same server I recommend having a Cloud infrastructure with 1 small Meteor server, 1 Laravel server. 1 MySQL Database server and 1 NoSQL server. Each able to scale independently depending on the type of tasks. In this case for example during weekends the Meteor server can be scaled down because there are less clients connected while the Laravel server scales up to process intense stuff.

This setup is also pretty redundant. When the complex Laravel app fails, clients won't notice. On the other hand when there is a high amount of clients, Laravel just continues its tasks without disturbance